# Link tag not showing on front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, tinymce, ejs

I am using tinyMCE as a text editor on my node application. Using RESTful routing I have created a typical create route that allows me to create a blog post ([see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWLIL.png). I am using express/mongoose/mongodb as the back end. Using ejs, the show route of a blog post is rendering the html entered through tinyMCE such as headings and paragraph tags. However, my issue is that links and images do not seem to be showing on the front end when added through tinyMCE. Upon inspection, both the src for the image and the href for the links are not stored in the database despite being added in tinyMCE.

[Here is me adding an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckpZK.png)

[Here is me adding a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGo4E.png)

[MongoDB entry with no src or href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWqTo.png)

Here is the relevant code for the create route

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- use TINYMCE for textarea -->
                <label for="blogContent">Blog Content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="blog[body]" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10" type="hidden"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  styleselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | image link | removeformat | help',
});
</script>
```

Comment: You couldn't have given any *less* information... There are so many reasons for this to happen we can't even begin to try to help you.  Add some more information.  Are you simply pasting "http://www.google.com" or are you pasting a full a tag (<a href="www.google.com">google</a>)?  How are you submitting the contents of the tinyMCE?  How does the backend write to the db?  Does the rest of the text in the textarea get saved?  how are you displaying the data?  Especially confusing is that you say it is not saved, but that the link appears in the front end...

Comment: Ok I updated it with more information

Comment: If you remove tinymce and enter the html directly into the textarea, does it work? I'm wondering if a) something in the backed is doing this or b) perhaps you are using a buggy version of tinymce... Is it the most recent? Looking at the docs I don't see anything specific about stripping/keeping attributes for the current version, just tags

Comment: Yes if I remove tinyMCE the textarea works just fine. I have read over the docs and was not sure if I'm missing some key component. Also I am using the script provided by tinyMCE so I assume the latest version. <script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>

Comment: Seems like you should opan a query on their forum or issue tracker... I'm not seeing anything in the defaults. Maaaaybe try setting extended_valid_elements to a(href) but that would imply valid_elements is being overridden somewhere.  Also one of the plugins might be doing something but at a glance nothing popped out at me

Answer (score 0):

If the link appears in the editor but does not end up in the database it would seem that somewhere in the process of posting and saving the data that the `src` attribute was removed.

If you look at the HTML source at the moment you get it from TinyMCE is the `src` attribute still present on the `img` tag?  If so this is not a TinyMCE issue but an issue somewhere in your post/save process.

Comment: As soon as I press submit on my form the src is simply unknown whether I post a local file or an outside url. What info do you need me to display to see if I'm saving the data wrong?

Comment: How are you getting the data out of TinyMCE?  Is the src attribute present at that moment?  If so your issue is not with TinyMCE but something else in your application's code.